# What are the components with the triangular symbol on this schematic?

Tags: schematics, components

This circuit diagram is of an Atari 2600. I have circled the components that I want to know about. Can you please tell me what they are and why are they used here?

[image]

Comment: It's labeled right on the schematic, with an arrow pointing to your red circle at the bottom right.

Comment: Offtopic but, Is that schematic hand-drawn?

Comment: No @MightyBeard007. I saw about thus in a youtube video from the channel computerphile. From there I searched on the internet and found the schematic.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The ic is a CD4050 hex buffer according to the schematic. This device basically 'strengthens' as in the output has a better current drive capability vs the logic signals from the TIA chip. The 4 buffers along with the resistors for a DAC (digital to analog converter) used to generate what I would assume is the color/video signal.

The CD4050 is a common and cheap ic.

Comment: The buffer used in digital electronics is used to pass the exact input to output so how does it strengthen the logic signals from the TIA chip?

Comment: It isn't passing through the input to output like a wire, it's an active device which copies the input to the output, the output drivers in the buffer are probably stronger than those in the TIA.

Comment: Thanks @Colin. I was under the assumption that buffer works as a wire just passing. Your comment helped. I will look more into it.